# react-redux Component failing to load at the first API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing an issue in react-redux where I navigate to the Component it crashes at the first API call, after a page refresh it works perfectly.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentUser();
    bsCustomFileInput.init();
    if (this.props.response.response) {
      this.setState({
        firstName: this.props.response.response.firstName,
        lastName: this.props.response.response.lastName,
        slug: this.props.response.response.slug,
        email: this.props.response.response.email,
        phoneNumber: this.props.response.response.phoneNumber,
        address: this.props.response.response.address,
        zipcode: this.props.response.response.zipcode,
        aboutYourself: this.props.response.response.aboutYourself
      });
    }
    this.props.updateMyProfileStart();
  }
.........
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getCurrentUser: () => dispatch(actions.getCurrentUser()),
    onUpdateMyProfile: userData =>
      dispatch(actions.updateMyProfileSuccess(userData)),
    updateMyProfileStart: () => dispatch(actions.updateMyProfileStart())
  };
};
```

I am using redux-persist to maintain the state.

The error log

```
ProfileSettings.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of null
    at ProfileSettings.componentDidMount (ProfileSettings.js:68)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:19814)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:22803)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:22541)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:22381)
    at finishSyncRender (react-dom.development.js:21807)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21793)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:597)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:552)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a value to the state that would indicate that the user is loading instead of trying to access data in the state that doesn't exist yet. Get the user and the loading state with a mapStateToProps and it'll work

Comment: @HMR can you please extend on that?

Comment: There are [plenty of examples](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/loading-data-in-react-redux-thunk-redux-saga-suspense-hooks-666b21da1569/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what the problem is because I don't see enough of your code. However, to me it sounds like a Promise issue. It could be that getCurrentUser is asynchronous in which case it is returning a Promise.

You could try:

```
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCurrentUser()
            .then(() => {
                bsCustomFileInput.init();
                if (this.props.response.response) {
                    this.setState({
                        firstName: this.props.response.response.firstName,
                        lastName: this.props.response.response.lastName,
                        slug: this.props.response.response.slug,
                        email: this.props.response.response.email,
                        phoneNumber: this.props.response.response.phoneNumber,
                        address: this.props.response.response.address,
                        zipcode: this.props.response.response.zipcode,
                        aboutYourself: this.props.response.response.aboutYourself
                    });
                }
                this.props.updateMyProfileStart();
            })

    }
```